# Can I reload my node's config from the command line without restarting the node?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I needed to make some config changes to my node and I'd like to reload the config without stopping the node and then restarting it. Is that possible? I don't see any related RPC commands on the wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. There's a [feature request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/309) about this, but I don't think a feature like that has been added.